# Neo4j, Cypher: Graphity System

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a graphity system to fetch news feed of a user.

A User is connected to his/her friends with an `Ego` relationship which stores the `ID` of that  user. But I found out Neo4j reuses the ID of a node if that node is deleted.

So, is there any other way to create a graphity system and keep track of the `Ego` relations without saving the `user id` in it. As creating a node for `Ego` instead of a `relationship` loses the easiness of traversal of news feed.

For example this is the query to unfollow a user

```
MATCH (u:User), (f:User) 
WHERE ID(u)=4084079 AND ID(f)=4105710 
MATCH (x1)-[r1:Ego{user_id:ID(u)}]->(f)-[r2:Ego{user_id:ID(u)}]->(x2) 
FOREACH (s IN CASE WHEN r1 IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [r1] END | 
   FOREACH (t IN CASE WHEN r2 IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [r2] END | 
     CREATE (x1)-[:Ego{user_id:ID(u)}]->(x2) 
     DELETE s, t
   )
) 
WITH u, f 
MATCH (u)-[r:Follow]->(f) 
DELETE r
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can also store the external user-id and then check the user-id against the store-one?

Otherwise don't lookup via id but user-id.

Comment: Hm, I got your point. But the concern is if using ID as properties is causing to increase the RAM usage in any unexpected way?

If its not caused by this, then I can get away this as users will never be deleted.

Actually this question is an extension to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344479/neo4j-server-consuming-ram-excessively/26345908?noredirect=1#comment41413719_26345908

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189351/neo4j-server-clear-the-cache-in-ram

and the reason is still unsolved for me..